# Positive and negative index of inertia of certain quadratic function

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have the following quadratic function $$\varphi=f_1^2+f_2^2+\dots+f_p^2-f_{p+1}^2-\dots-f_{p+q}^2,$$ where $f_i$ are real linear functionals of the variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Prove that the positive index of inertia of $\varphi$ is $\leq p$ and negative index of inertia is $\leq q$.

I tried to solve this problem almost one week ago but had no ideas and tried it yesterday and also failed.

I would be very thankful if someone will show how to prove this problem, please!

**EDIT (this is the detailed version of the proof given by clhpeterson):**

I got the general idea of your proof but when I was trying to write it rigorously I ran into some moments which are not so clear to me.

So denote by $T$ the mapping $V\to \mathbb{R}^{p+q}$ given by $T(\mathbf{x})=AX^t$ where $A$ is the same as in your solution and $X^t$ is column of coordinates of $\mathbf{x}\in V$. Also let $B:\mathbb{R}^{p+q}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $B(\mathbf{y})=y_1^2+\dots+y_p^2-y_{p+1}^2-\dots-y_{p+q}^2$. Then it is easy to show that $\varphi=B\circ T$ where $\varphi=f_1^2+\dots+f_p^2-f_{p+1}^2-\dots-f_{p+q}^2$.

Suppose quadratic function $\varphi$ has positive index $>p$ then $\exists W$ subspace of $V$ with $\dim W=p+1$ such that $\varphi |_W$ is positively definite. Also let's denote by $\hat{T}=T|_W$ and you considered the linear map $\hat{T}:W\to \mathbb{R}^{p+q}$. So by rank-nullity we have 2 cases: $\dim \operatorname{Im} \hat{T}=p+1$ and $\dim \ker \hat{T}>0$.

If $\dim \ker \hat{T}>0$ then $\exists \mathbf{x}\neq \mathbf{0}\in W$ such that $T(\mathbf{x})=0$ and then $\varphi(\mathbf{x})=B\circ T(\mathbf{x})=B(0)=0$ but since $\varphi|_W$ is positively definite then we have $\varphi(\mathbf{x})>0$ which is contradiction.

Suppose that $\dim \operatorname{Im}\hat{T}=p+1$ then $\hat{T}(W)$ is a $(p+1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$. Since $B$ has an index $p$ then $B|_{\hat{T}(W)}$ is not positively definite. It means that $\exists \mathbf{y}\neq 0\in \hat{T}(W)$ such that $B(\mathbf{y})\leq 0$, i.e. $\exists \mathbf{x}\neq 0\in W$ such that $\mathbf{y}=\hat{T}(\mathbf{x})$. Since $\varphi|_W$ is positively definite then $0<\varphi(\mathbf{x})=B(T(\mathbf{x}))=B(\mathbf{y})\leq 0$. And this is the contradiction. Am i right?

BTW, I guess in your proof you are using this fact which seems correct but I cannot prove formally:

> **Lemma:** Let $\xi:V\to\mathbb{R}$ be a quadratic function and $\dim V=n$.  Let $p<n$ is positive index of inertia of $\xi$. Let $W$ is a
>   subspace of $V$ with $\dim W=p+1$ then $\xi|_W$ is not positively
>   definite.

Proof: Suppose that $\hat{\xi}:=\xi|_W$ is positively definite then there is a basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_{p+1}\}$ of $W$ such that the matrix of $\hat{\xi}$ in this basis is $E_{p+1}$ identity matrix of the size $p+1$.

Let's complete the basis of $W$ up to a basis of $V$ with vectors $e_{p+2},\dots,e_n$.  Then I stucked...

Comment: Overall this looks correct. Regarding your lemma: I'm not sure which definition you are using for positive index of inertia. One definition is that it is the largest dimension of a subspace you can restrict to and have your quadratic form be positive definite. Another definition is as the number of positive eigenvalues of the matrix representing your quadratic form (you can write every quadratic form as $x^T A x$ for some symmetric matrix $A$). The equivalence of these definitions is sorta kinda the content of Sylvester's law of inertia.

Comment: @clhpeterson, my definition is the following: positive index of inertia is the number of +1's in the diagonal of its matrix in canonical form. Could you show the proof of this lemma using my definition, please?

Answer (score 1):

Let's put all of our linear functionals $f_i$ into a matrix (as the rows) so we get a matrix mapping $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$, call it $A$. Recall that the positive index of inertia of a quadratic form is the largest dimension of any space on which the quadratic form restricts to be positive definite. Clearly the index of the quadratic form $y_1^2 + \dots + y_p^2 - y_{p+1}^2 - \dots - y_{p+q}^2$ has positive index $p$ and negative index $q$. Call this quadratic form $B$. Now we're interested in the indices of the quadratic form $f_1^2 + \dots + f_p^2 - f_{p+1}^2 - \dots - f_{p+q}^2$. We can think of this as first applying our matrix $A$, and then applying the quadratic form $B$. We are interested in the dimension of the largest subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that when we do this composition restricted to this subspace, we get a positive definite form. Suppose we have a $p+1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, call it $V$. Then either some element in $V$ gets sent to zero by $A$, or the image of $V$ under $A$ is also dimension $p+1$.

In the first case, clearly our composite quadratic form on an element sent to zero (call it $v$) by $A$ takes the value zero, so the composite quadratic form is not positive definite on the subspace generated by $v$, hence it's not positive definite on $V$ either. In the second case, we know that the quadratic form $B$ restricted to the image of $V$ cannot be positive definite because the index of $B$ is exactly $p$. What this shows is that there is no $p+1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for which the composite quadratic form restricted to it is positive definite. Hence the positive index is at most $p$. The argument for negative index is of course virtually identical.

Comment: Row vectors are basically the same thing as linear functionals (i.e. maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$). Thus one way to think about a matrix is as a bunch of row vectors, but it also works the other way: given a bunch of functionals you can build a matrix. If $f_1, \dots, f_k$ are linear functionals, map a vector $v$ to the vector $[f_1(v), f_2(v), \dots, f_k(v)]^T$. If $f_i = a_{i1} x_1 + \dots + a_{in} x_n$, then the $i$th row of the matrix looks like $[a_{i1} \dots a_{in}]$.

Comment: Rank nullity theorem tells you that when you apply a linear transformation (matrix) to a $k$-dimensional space, then the dimension of the image plus the dimension of the kernel is equal to $k$. Thus either the dimension of the image is equal to $k$, or the dimension of the kernel is at least one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a answer to the original question.

Note that any linear functional $x \mapsto l(x)$ can be written as $l(x) = f^T x$
for some $f$ and we see that $l^2(x) = x^T f f^T x$, so we can identify $l^2$ with the
dyad $f f^T$.

Then $\phi(x) = x^T f_1f_1^T x + \cdots + x^T f_pf_p^T x - x^T f_{p+1}f_{p+1}^T x - \cdots - x^T f_{p+q}f_{p+q}^T x$.

Let $P=\sum_{k \le p} f_kf_k^T$ and $Q=\sum_{k > p} f_kf_k^T$. Then 
$\phi(x) = x^TAx$ where $A=P-Q$.
Note that $\operatorname{rk}P \le p$ and $\operatorname{rk}Q \le q$.

$A$ is symmetric and has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $v_k$ with
corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_k$.

Let $V = \operatorname{sp} \{v_k\}_{\lambda_k > 0}$. We want to show $\dim V \le p$.

Suppose $\dim V > p$. Since $\operatorname{rk}P \le p$ we have $\dim \ker P \ge n-p$.
Hence there is some non zero $v \in V \cap \ker P$. However, since $\phi(v) \le 0$ this
contradicts the definition of $V$.

A similar analysis applied to $-\phi$ shows the corresponding result for the egative index.

Comment: I am a bit confused to be honest. Are you proving the problem or the lemma? What is $\psi(x)$? I guess the notion $f_k^T$ is quite meaningless. Maybe i am wrong

Comment: I added some clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a easy proof using a proposition of rank of real matrices.

Note that $\mathrm{rank}(A^{\text T}A)=\mathrm{rank}(A)$ ,we know positive quadratic form
$$
(AX)^{\text T}(AX)=X^{\text T}A^{\text T}AX
$$
has rank $\le$ size of $A$.

Observing that $(AX)^{\text T}(AX)$ is actually the form $f_1^2+\cdots+f_p^2$, it can be reduced to $y_1^2+\cdots+y_r^2$. Meanwhile, we can stabalize these $y_1,\cdots,y_r$ and transform $f_{p+1}^2+\cdots+f_{p+q}^2$ to similar form.

Now the positive index (even some have being deleted by the latter) must $\le p$.